# MySQL table is not accessible from console

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have a problem with the info written in the database. I write the information but is not there.

What I'm trying to do is creating a table from a csv.

I use from python:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="diego",
password="xxxx6667",
database ="dccDummy"
)
cursor = mydb.cursor(dictionary=True)
sql = "SELECT * FROM DccDepts"
cursor.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print(rows)
```

and the result is:

```
[{'DeptoID': 1, 'DccDept': 'Flujo y Volumen', 'DccCentro': 'Fisica', 'PermisosDept': 1, 'pubdate': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 3, 19, 36, 0, 406371)}, {'DeptoID': 2, 'DccDept': 'Termodinámica', 'DccCentro': 'Fisica', 'PermisosDept': 1, 'pubdate': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 3, 19, 47, 41, 431015)}, {'DeptoID': 3, 'DccDept': 'Patrones cuanticos', 'DccCentro': 'Fisica', 'PermisosDept': 1, 'pubdate': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 3, 19, 47, 59, 161024)}, {'DeptoID': 4, 'DccDept': 'outside', 'DccCentro': 'Not Here', 'PermisosDept': 0, 'pubdate': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 3, 19, 47, 59, 161024)}]
```

This is what I write from the files, and it's OK.

**But if I go to the mysql console or even to the workbench the database exists and the table also, but the table is empty**.

Does anyone have a clue to figure this out?

Here is the full code:

```
import mysql.connector
import csv

table1 = "dccdepts"
table2 = "dccusers"
table3 = "dccprocs"

def insert_Dept(ordered_dict,mydb):
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    sqlDccDepts = "INSERT INTO DccDepts(DeptoID, DccDept, DccCentro, PermisosDept, pubdate) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
    try:
        for row in ordered_dict:
            args = str(row['id']), str(row['dcc_dept']), str(row['dcc_centro']), str(row['dcc_PermisosDept']), str(row['pub_date'])
            print(args)
            cursor.execute(sqlDccDepts, args)
            if cursor.lastrowid:
                print('last insert id', cursor.lastrowid)
            else:
                print('last insert id not found') 
        verifica_escritura("DccDepts", mydb)
    except: print("error")
          
def verifica_escritura (table,mydb):
    cursor = mydb.cursor(dictionary=True)
    sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table
    cursor.execute(sql)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    print(rows)
    

def funcion():
    try:
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="diego",
        password="xxxx6667",
        database ="dccDummy"
        )
        
        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        sql = "DROP DATABASE dccDummy"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        print("Existe base")
    
    except:       
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="diego",
        password="xxxx6667",
        )
        print ("no database dccDummy")

    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql = "CREATE DATABASE dccDummy"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    
    with open('dccDepts.new.csv', 'r') as f:
        file_read = csv.DictReader(f)
        ordered_dict = list(file_read)
        #print(ordered_dict[1])
        #print(ordered_dict[1].keys())
        #print(ordered_dict[1].value())
    
    sql = "USE dccDummy;"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    
    sql = "CREATE TABLE DccDepts ( \
            DeptoID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, \
            DccDept VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE, \
            DccCentro VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, \
            PermisosDept INT(2), \
            pubdate datetime(6) NOT NULL \
            );"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    insert_Dept(ordered_dict,mydb)
    return ()
    
def main():
    funcion()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: (original author of mysql.connector here!) I do not see you committing the transaction.

Comment: I should commit the transaction? Wait what? ok how can I do this in python?

Comment: I did it, :D gut

Answer (score 0):

[The `mydb.commit()` is missing](https://geert.vanderkelen.org/2010/dont-forget-the-commit-in-mysql/). DDL (Data Definition Language) statements are commited right away, but your inserted data are by default not. That is why later, you will not see your data.

Example (note that example is from 2010, should still do the trick):

```py
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(db='test')
cur = cnx.cursor()

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE innodb_t1 (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
c1 VARCHAR(128),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB""")

ins = "INSERT INTO innodb_t1 (id,c1) VALUES (%s,%s)"
cur.execute(ins,
(1,'MySQL Support Team _is_ already the best',))
cnx.commit()
cur.close()
cnx.close()
```

Comment: Nice, don't forget to tick the Answer as accepted. Thanks!